# How to enable CORS in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, cors, laravel-5.8

I am in Laravel 5.8  - I kept getting this CORS issue

[image]

I've tried

```
php artisan make:middleware Cors
```

Add these code

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Middleware;
use Closure;
class Cors
{
  public function handle($request, Closure $next)
  {
    return $next($request)
      ->header(‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’, ‘*’)
      ->header(‘Access-Control-Allow-Methods’, ‘GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS’)
      ->header(‘Access-Control-Allow-Headers’, ‘X-Requested-With, Content-Type, X-Token-Auth, Authorization’);
  }
}
```

restart my local Apache 2 `sudo apachectl -k restart`

Open up `app/Http/Kernel.php` - added this 1 line

```
protected $routeMiddleware = [
        'auth' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authenticate::class,
        'auth.basic' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\AuthenticateWithBasicAuth::class,
        'bindings' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
        'can' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authorize::class,
        'guest' => \App\Http\Middleware\RedirectIfAuthenticated::class,
        'throttle' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ThrottleRequests::class,
        'admin' => \App\Http\Middleware\AdminMiddleware::class,
        'dev' => \App\Http\Middleware\DevMiddleware::class,
        'cors' => \App\Http\Middleware\Cors::class, <----- 
    ];
```

refresh the site, go to console, still see the same CORS issue

How would one go about and debug this further?

Comment: Have you applied the middleware to the route in the routes file?

Comment: instead of $routeMiddleware put it in $middleware which runs during every request to your application

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try [laravel-cors](https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-cors) package that allows you to send Cross-Origin Resource Sharing headers with Laravel middleware configuration.

Comment: I had the same issue and this package didn't do it for me but this did [laravel-cors](https://github.com/spatie/laravel-cors). Hope this helps someone.

Comment: @S.Sid Glad I could help.

Comment: nothing works for me(((
I already added headers manually in bootstrap/app.php and see this headers in postman, but it still not works(((((

Comment: @denys Siebov let me know if something works for you as I am facing the same problem and above mentioned solutions dont work

Answer (score 7):

## **First solution**

Try to set the CORS middleware as a **global middleware**.

the `handle function` in the `CORS middleware`:

```
 public function handle($request, Closure $next)
 {
  return $next($request)
   ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*')
   ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, PUT, PATCH, DELETE, OPTIONS')
   ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type, Authorization');
 }
```

to add this middleware globally, go to `App\Http\Kernel`, and add this line in the `$middleware` array:

```
\App\Http\Middleware\Cors::class,
```

---

## **Second solution**

you can also add this code in the `bootstrap/app.php`

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, PUT, PATCH, DELETE, OPTIONS');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type, Authorization');
```

hope it works!

Comment: it is giving  header() expects at most 3 parameters, 7 given

Comment: I put this lines at bottom of these files, cache cleared, but block persist

Answer (score 4):

Since `Nov 10, 2020` Laravel add build-in configuration for this, you can find it in `config/cors.php`, look at https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/9.x/config/cors.php

Answer (score 3):

Add below to you .htaccess (just add to the destination site and origin site)

```
Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Methods "POST, GET, OPTIONS, DELETE, PUT"
Header always set Access-Control-Max-Age "1000"
Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Headers "x-requested-with, Content-Type, origin, authorization, accept, client-security-token"

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} OPTIONS
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1 [R=200,L]
```

Hope it saves someone time, happy coding!!!