# "Error: Blocked CORS Policy - No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' Header Present"

Tags: reactjs, laravel, laravel-blade, ckeditor5

I have problem = "Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:8000/admin/image-upload/' from origin 'http://127.0.0.1:8000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource."

This my file :
// Create.jsx

```
import AuthenticatedLayout from "../../Layouts/AuthenticatedLayout";
// import { FontAwesomeIcon } from "@fortawesome/react-fontawesome";
// import { faAdd } from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons';
import { useForm, Head } from "@inertiajs/react";
import FormPost from "./FormPost";
import { Sidebar } from "@/Components/Dashboard/Sidebar";
import HeaderAll from "@/Components/HeaderAll";

export function Create({ auth, categories }) {
  const { data, setData, errors, processing, post } = useForm({
    title: "",
    status: "published",
    content: "",
    category_id: "",
    image: null,
  });
  const submit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    post(route("posts.store"));
    // setData("image", null);
  };
  return (
    <>
      <HeaderAll user={auth.user} />
      <Head title="Creat-Post" />
      <Sidebar />
      {/* Content */}
      <div className="w-full pt-20 px-4 sm:px-6 md:px-8 lg:ps-72">
        <h1 className="app-page-title">Create Post</h1>
        <div className="app-card app-card-account shadow-sm d-flex flex-column align-items-start">
          <div className="app-card-header p-3 border-bottom-0">
            <div className="row align-items-center gx-3">
              <div className="col-auto">
                <div className="app-icon-holder"></div>
              </div>
              <div className="col-auto">
                <h4 className="app-card-title">Create New Post</h4>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div className="app-card-body px-4 w-100">
            <FormPost
              data={data}
              setData={setData}
              errors={errors}
              processing={processing}
              onSubmit={submit}
              categories={categories}
            />
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      {/* <ReactQuill theme="snow" /> */}
    </>
  );
}

export default Create;
```

and this my Ckeditor from "FormPost"
// Ckeditor.jsx

```
import { CKEditor } from "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-react";
// import { Link } from "@inertiajs/react";
import { ClassicEditor } from "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-editor-classic";
import { Bold, Italic, Underline } from "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-basic-styles";
import { Essentials } from "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-essentials";
import { Paragraph } from "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-paragraph";
import { SimpleUploadAdapter } from "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-upload";
import { Heading } from "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-heading";
import { Link, AutoLink } from "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-link";
import {
  List,
  ListProperties,
  AdjacentListsSupport,
} from "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-list";
import { Font } from "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-font";
import { Title } from "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-heading";
import { Autoformat } from "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-autoformat";
import {
  Image,
  ImageCaption,
  ImageResizeEditing,
  ImageResizeHandles,
  ImageToolbar,
  ImageUpload,
} from "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-image";
import { Alignment } from "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-alignment";
// import MiniCssExtractPlugin from "mini-css-extract-plugin";

// const csrfToken = document
//   .querySelector('meta[name="csrf-token"]')
//   .getAttribute("content");
// const uploadUrl = `http://localhost:8000/admin/image-upload?_token=${csrfToken}`;

// const uploadUrl = "{{ route('image.upload') }}";
const uploadUrl = "http://localhost:8000/admin/image-upload/";

export default function Ckeditor({ data, setData }) {
  return (
    <>
      <CKEditor
        // className="ml-8"
        editor={ClassicEditor}
        config={{
          plugins: [
            Autoformat,
            Paragraph,
            Bold,
            Italic,
            Essentials,
            Underline,
            Image,
            ImageUpload,
            SimpleUploadAdapter,
            Heading,
            Link,
            List,
            ListProperties,
            AdjacentListsSupport,
            AutoLink,
            ImageCaption,
            ImageToolbar,
            ImageResizeEditing,
            ImageResizeHandles,
            Font,
            Title,
            Alignment,
          ],
          title: {
            placeholder: "My custom placeholder for the title",
          },
          placeholder: "My custom placeholder for the body",
          toolbar: [
            "undo",
            "redo",
            "|",
            "heading",
            "|",
            "bold",
            "italic",
            "underline",
            "alignment",
            "|",
            "bulletedList",
            "numberedList",
            "|",
            "fontSize",
            "fontFamily",
            "fontColor",
            "fontBackgroundColor",
            "|",
            "toggleImageCaption",
            "imageTextAlternative",
            // "ckboxImageEdit",
            "image",
            "imageCaption",
            "imageResizeEditing",
            "imageResizeHandles",
            "imageUpload",
            "|",
            "link",
          ],
          list: {
            multiBlock: false,
            properties: {
              styles: true,
              startIndex: true,
              reversed: true,
            },
          },

          simpleUpload: {
            uploadUrl: uploadUrl,
            withCredentials: true,

            // Headers sent along with the XMLHttpRequest to the upload server.
            headers: {
              "X-CSRF-TOKEN": document
                .querySelector('meta[name="csrf-token"]')
                .getAttribute("content"),
              Authorization: "Bearer <JSON Web Token>",
            },
          },
        }}
        tag="textarea"
        data={data.content}
        onChange={(_, editor) => {
          const content = editor.getData();
          setData("content", content);
        }}
      />
    </>
  );
}
```

and this my backend Controller
//ImageUploadController.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class ImageUploadController extends Controller
{
  public function storeImage(Request $request)
  {
    if ($request->hasFile('upload')) {
      $originName = $request->file('upload')->getClientOriginalName();
      $fileName = pathinfo($originName, PATHINFO_FILENAME);
      $extension = $request->file('upload')->getClientOriginalExtension();
      $fileName = $fileName . '_' . time() . '.' . $extension;

      $request->file('upload')->move(public_path('upload-image'), $fileName);

      $url = asset('upload-image/' . $fileName);
      return response()->json(['fileName' => $fileName, 'uploaded' => 1, 'url' => $url]);
      // return redirect()->route('image.upload');
    }
  }
}
```

I'm here using Laravel with React JS,, please help me to fix this :)

I have tried changing the Cors.php in Laravel
like this for example:

```
<?php

return [

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Cross-Origin Resource Sharing (CORS) Configuration
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Here you may configure your settings for cross-origin resource sharing
    | or "CORS". This determines what cross-origin operations may execute
    | in web browsers. You are free to adjust these settings as needed.
    |
    | To learn more: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS
    |
    */

    'paths' => ['api/*', 'sanctum/csrf-cookie'],

    'allowed_methods' => ['*'],

    'allowed_origins' => **['http://localhost:8000'],**

    'allowed_origins_patterns' => [],

    'allowed_headers' => ['*'],

    'exposed_headers' => [],

    'max_age' => 0,

    'supports_credentials' => false,

];
```

on this code " 'allowed_origins' => ['http://localhost:8000'],"

Comment: You're trying to do a request to `admin/image-upload/`, but your CORS config only allows requests to `api/*` and `sanctum/csrf-cookie`. Try adding `admin/*` or `*` to the `paths`-section of the config-file

Answer (score 0):

In `bootstrap/app.php` add:

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, PUT, PATCH, DELETE, OPTIONS');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type, Authorization');
```

This is the same issue as:
[How to enable CORS in Laravel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55346154/how-to-enable-cors-in-laravel)

Comment: As is noted in the repo you linked, the `fruitcake/laravel-cors` package is deprecated for newer versions of Laravel: _"This package is deprecated because all supported Laravel versions now include the CORS middleware in the core."_

Comment: @antoine

**fruitcake cannot install:**

  Problem 1
    - Root composer.json requires fruitcake/laravel-cors 2.1 -> satisfiable by fruitcake/laravel-cors[v2.1.0].
    - fruitcake/laravel-cors v2.1.0 requires illuminate/support ^6|^7|^8|^9 -> found illuminate/support[v6.0.0, ..., v6.20.44, v7.0.0, ..., v7.30.6, v8.0.0, ..., v8.83.27, v9.0.0, ..., v9.52.16] but these were not loaded, likely because it conflicts with another require.

Comment: @CerebralFart so how to fix ??

Comment: @rraangga I edited the answer using another answer from the linked issue. I hope it fixes your issue